# Handling errors in wsshellobj.Run() when the path for application is wrong

Tags: vba, excel

I want to know what is the return type when I call the below function in my vba project.

`Ret = wsshellobj.Run(application_filepath, True)`

I need to incorporate error handling at this point. what I have done is

```
If Err.Number <> Ret Or Err.Number = 0 Then
  'Error Handler code
End If
```

But this doesn't seem to work

Thanks,

Gana

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps?

**TOPIC**: Method:  WshShell.Run

**LINK**: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/quickref/wshshell_run.html

**EXTRACT FROM THE ABOVE LINK**:

The Run method creates a new process and runs the command specified by strCommand. The optional parameter intWindowStyle is used to set the window style of the program being run. If the optional parameter bWaitOnReturn is set to True (default is False), then Run will return the return value returned by strCommand. Otherwise it returns 0. Also, if bWaitOnReturn is set to True, then the script will suspend its execution until strCommand finishes.